# CakePHP 2.x ACL - Control at owner level

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I am able to control my application using `ACL`, everything done perfectly and application is working smooth with `ACL` and `Auth`.

Now the problem is:

I have two tables, `users` and `posts`. there is no `RBAC` (role based access control).
I am setting `deny` and `allow` for each user like follow.

```
//allow User1 to do everything
$user->id=1;
$this->ACL->allow($user,'controllers');

//allow User2 to add, edit and view the posts 
$user->id=2;
$this->Acl->deny($user, 'controllers');
$this->Acl->allow($user, 'controllers/Posts');
```

but here I am getting one problem:

`user2` is getting access to `edit` the `posts` of `user1`.

example:

`User1` created a `post1`.

now `User2` logged in now he can edit the `User1`'s post (i.e. `post1- /localhost/myApp/posts/edit/1`)

**Question: How can I set ACL permission to this problem, The owner of the post can only edit the post and others can not.**

I can achieve this in controller level simply checking

```
if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'] == $Post['Post']['user_id']){
    // you're the owner, so u can edit
}else{
    //u cant edit, this is not ur post
}
```

but I need `ACL` to work here, Is it possible?, Please help

Thanks

Comment: if its a javascript question I will get immediate results, but my bad luck, this cakephp.  very bad, :(

Comment: don't sure if it works bu did you try somethink like: `$this->Acl->allow($user, 'controllers/Posts'/edit/1)` an so on?

Comment: @arilia , thanks for commenting i tried it, not working can you suggest any other solutions :)

Comment: I've never userd ACL so deeply but I think you must first set your post as acos  `public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'controlled'));` and create a node for every post  too, the same way you create a node for every user

Comment: Reading the documentation seems that you can create an ACO for every post and set an user level permissions for it. But you still have to check the permission using`$this->Acl->check(...)`. ACL authorization handler just check the permission at an action level. See the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-actionsauthorize)

Comment: thanks, I will try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's how I would do

first of all tell Cake that `Post` model is an `ACO`

```
 // Post.php model file
 $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'controlled'));
```

this way every time you create a new post cake will automatically create an item in the `acos` table.

pay attention: you'll have to manually create the node for the previously created Posts, this way:

```
// for every Post in your posts table

$this->Acl->Aco->create(array('alias' => 'Post', 'id' => 123));
$this->Acl->Aco->save();
```

then you have to define a `parentNode()` function in your Post Model file

```
// Post.php model file
public function parentNode() {
    return null;
}
```

Now the ACL auth handler check form permission just at an action level. In other words it just checks that you're allowed to access the action. Then it demands other checks at a controller level by the `isAuthorized()` function.

so first you have to set the permission for every node

```
$this->Acl->allow($user, 'controllers/Posts/edit/123')
```

then in your controller you have to do

```
 // PostsController.php 
 public function isAuthorized($user = null) {

    if ($this->request->action === 'edit') {
        $user = // retrieve the user array. i.e. from Session
        $post_id = $this->request->$this->request->pass[0];
        $post = array('alias' => 'Post', 'id' => $post_id );
        return this->Acl->check($user, $post);
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

you can also implement parentNode() function to return the owner of the Post instead of null

```
// Post.php model file

// just an hint, the actual code should be 
// a bit more complex
public function parentNode() {
    $user_id = $this->field('user_id');
    return array('User' => array('id' => $user_id));
}
```

this way don't have to set the permission for every single post because cake will check if the user has access to the parent node of the Post (who is a user too). So you just have to set the permission for every user

```
$this->Acl->allow($user, $user);
```

If you follow this method remember to set the user as an ACO too

```
// User.php Model file

$actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'both'));
```

I did not test the code above so I guess there are a lot of typos and errors too. If I have time i'll do some tests and improve my answer in the next days

Comment: Thanks, I will try this immediately, Looks like decent solution :)